# расстояние между двумя точками через класс js

Tags: javascript

Напишите класс JS, который представляет точку. Он имеет координаты x и y в качестве свойств, которые устанавливаются через конструктор, и статический метод для определения расстояния между двумя точками, называемый distance ().
пример:

```
let p1 = new Point(5, 5);
let p2 = new Point(9, 8);
console.log(Point.distance(p1, p2));
```

помогите пж

Comment: Ну попытайся. Пожалуйста! ;)

Comment: (теорема Пифагора)

Comment: я не понимаю как через код ето сделать, иначе сюда не писал бы

Comment: ну Вы формулу вывели?

Comment: Метод distance () должен получить два объекта Point в качестве параметров.

Метод distance () должен возвращать число, расстояние между двумя точечными параметрами.

Comment: Вот товарищ тебе про математический аспект уже всё сказал. Осталось открыть [интернет](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) и поковыряйся. Сам же научишься. Лучше поймёшь.

Comment: большое спасибо

Comment: static distance(a, b) {
    const dx = a.x - b.x;
    const dy = a.y - b.y;

    return Math.hypot(dx, dy);
  }
здесь была постоянно ошыбка у меня, и да надо учиться гуглить ещо спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  disance(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt(((p2.x - p1.x) ** 2) + ((p2.y - p1.y) ** 2));
  }
}
const point = new Point();
console.log(point.disance(new Point(5, 7), new Point(11, 24)));
```